# Python Time convertor from seconds to days, hours, minutes & seconds

Tags: python-3.x

I am brand new to python.  i am working in v3.3. I am trying to take an input of seconds and break it out to days, hours, minutes and seconds.  I also need to not print if the hours are 0 or the seconds are 0. The problem is that I don't seem to be calculating the seconds at all.  i put in 97765 seconds When I run it without the if else for seconds it gives me a 0 which is wrong and if I keep the if else it doesn't print anything which is also wrong.  I t should give me a remained of 5 seconds.

```
#Get the number of seconds
total_secs = int(input("How many seconds, in total?  " ))
#calculate those seconds into days
days = total_secs // 86400
secs_days = total_secs % 86400
#calculate the remainder into hours
hours = secs_days // 3600
secs_hours = secs_days % 3600
#calculate the remainder into minutes
minutes =  secs_hours // 60
secs_minutes = secs_hours % 60
#calculate the remainder into seconds
seconds = secs_minutes // 60
#print out days if the number is above 0
if days == 0:
    print("  ")
else:
    print("Days=", days)
#print the number of hours & minutes
    print("Hours=", hours)
    print("Minutes=", minutes)
#print out seconds if the number is above 0
if seconds == 0:
    print("  ")
else:
    print("Seconds=", seconds)
print('Thank you')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have a logical mistake

```
seconds = secs_minutes // 60
```

should actually just be

```
seconds = secs_minutes
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!  It works now - It is those little logic errors that always trip me up.

Comment: Good to know. If you feel my answer solved your problem, then please *accept* it by clicking on the tick-mark button on the left hand side.